# how to save multiple arrays to a mongodb database with one click of a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

The app requires users to enter Items, quantity, prices of goods etc. as part of a moneyIn transaction.But when the "blue" save button is clicked, only the last item (corry 7000...) is stored in the database. Note: The "red" save button does not save anything to the database it just makes the section invisible for the array list of items to show. How can I save all the Items created by the user as well as the moneyIn transaction all by a single click of the "blue" save button. Each item entered in the form shows up as an array if you try to display it on a console hence the reason for the way the title of my question is structured. A little help will be much appreciated, thank you.  My Code snippet:

```
const MoneyIn = () => { 

    const [totalAmountIn, setTotalAmountIn] = useState(0);
    const [amountRecieved, setAmountRecieved] = useState(0);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
    const [sellingPrice, setSellingPrice] = useState(0);
    const [sellingPriceOfTotal, setSellingPriceOfTotal] = useState(0);
    const [balanceDue, setBalanceDue] = useState(0);
    const [itemDescription, setItemDescription] = useState("");
    const [unitOfQuantity, setUnitOfQuantity] = useState("");
    const [quantityCount, setQuantityCount] = useState(1);
    const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);
    const [moneyInData, setMoneyInData] = useState([]);
    const [modeOfPayment, setModeOfPayment] = useState("");

let handleSaveItem = () => {
        const newItemData = { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, sellingPrice };
        setNewItems([...newItems, newItemData]); 
    }

let handleSaveMonyIn = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (totalAmountIn === 0 || itemDescription === "") {
            setSeverity("error")
            setMessage("Enter Amount and Item Description");
            setOpen(true)
        } else if (totalSellingPrice > totalAmountIn) {
            setSeverity("error")
            setMessage("Total Selling Prices cannot be bigger than Total amount");
            setOpen(true)
        }

        else {
            const newMoneyInData = { totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, itemDescription, modeOfPayment };
            setMoneyInData([...moneyInData, newMoneyInData]);
             
            //Save in the database
            Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/moneyIn',{
                totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, newItems, itemDescription, modeOfPayment
            }).then((response) => {alert('TRANSACTION CREATED')}).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
            Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/newItems', {productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, 
            sellingPrice,totalSellingPrice}).then((response) => console.log(response)).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
            console.log(newMoneyInData);
            document.getElementById("totalAndRecievedAmt").reset();
            document.getElementById("itemDescriptionFrm").reset();
            setSeverity("success");
            setMessage("Saved Successfully !!!");
            setOpen(true);
             setTotalAmountIn(0);
             setAmountRecieved(0);
             setBalanceDue(0);
             setItemDescription('');
             setNewItems([]);


        }
    }

}

//MoneyIn (or transaction) Data schema

const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const moneyInDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    totalAmountIn:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amountRecieved:{
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    balanceDue: {
        type: Number
    },
    itemDescription:{
        type: String
    },
    modeOfPayment:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('MoneyInData', moneyInDataSchema)

//newItems data Schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MoneyInData = require('./MoneyInData');
const newItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sellingPriceOfTotal:{
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    quantityCount: {
        type: Number
    },
    unitOfQuantity:{
        type: String
    },
    sellingPrice:{
        type: Number,
        required:true
    },
    sales:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MoneyInData'
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('NewItemsData', newItemsSchema);

//my Controller code that creates and retrieves newItems from the database

const getAllNewItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const newItemsData = await NewItemsData.find().populate('sales').select().lean()

    if (!newItemsData?.length) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No rescent transaction' })
    }
    res.json(newItemsData)
})

const createNewItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, sellingPrice}= req.body

    //confirm data
    if (!productName || !sellingPriceOfTotal || !quantityCount
        || !unitOfQuantity || !sellingPrice ) {

        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }

    const newItemsObj = { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, sellingPrice }

    const addNewItems = await NewItemsData.create(newItemsObj)

    if (addNewItems) {//created
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'New Item Recorded' })
        console.log(addNewItems)
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Item' })
    }

})
```

[image: a form to add details of items]

[image: When Item details are added]

[image: An image highlighting the save button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to save all the items created by the user and link them with a single transaction, you can create separate API endpoints to handle the two types of data (moneyIn and items).

instead of sending the `newItems` array as part of the `moneyInData` object, save the `moneyInData` first and then send the `newItems` separately

**Frontend Code**

```
const handleSaveMonyIn = (event) => {
    //.......
    else {
        const newMoneyInData = { totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, itemDescription, modeOfPayment };
        // save moneyInData first
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/moneyIn', newMoneyInData)
            .then((moneyInResponse) => {
                // after saving moneyInData, save newItems associated with this moneyIn
                const moneyInId = moneyInResponse.data._id; // create the server returns the created moneyIn _id in backend
                newItems.forEach((item) => {
                    Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/newItems', { ...item, sales: moneyInId })
                        .then((itemResponse) => {
                            console.log(itemResponse.data);
                        })
                        .catch((itemError) => {
                            console.error(itemError);
                        });
                });
              //  .... success messages
            })
            .catch((moneyInError) => {
                console.error(moneyInError);
            });
    }
}
```

**Backend Code**

you should handle the moneyIn and newItems routes separately.

```
// POST route to create moneyIn transaction
app.post("/moneyIn", async (req, res) => {
    const { totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, itemDescription, modeOfPayment } = req.body;
    const newMoneyInData = {
        totalAmountIn,
        amountRecieved,
        balanceDue,
        itemDescription,
        modeOfPayment
    };

    try {
        const moneyInData = await MoneyInData.create(newMoneyInData);
        res.status(201).json(moneyInData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to create moneyIn transaction" });
    }
});

// POST route to create new items associated with a moneyIn transaction
app.post("/newItems", async (req, res) => {
    const { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, sellingPrice, sales } = req.body;
    const newItemsData = {
        productName,
        sellingPriceOfTotal,
        quantityCount,
        unitOfQuantity,
        sellingPrice,
        sales // this should be the _id of the associated moneyIn transaction
    };

    try {
        const newItems = await NewItemsData.create(newItemsData);
        res.status(201).json(newItems);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to create new items" });
    }
});
```

by this you'll be able to create a single moneyIn transaction with multiple associated items and properly store them in the database I PRESSUME.
Thanks.

Comment: This was quite helpful having another approach to the same problem, didn't really consider that multiple post method, though I have figured out a way around, this is also a suitable answer. but I have got issues with implementing multiple get request, I raised a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77453130/program-constantly-executes-the-wrong-get-request-method  would like if you looked at it too, thanks.